# Sort Records according to associated data column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm feeling really dump that how could I sort records according to associated data column

I'm fetching records in my controller like

```
 @collection = @collection.includes(:countries).page(params[:page]).per(per_page)
```

and in my index page I'm doing like this

```
<tbody>
  <% @collection.each do |price_mapping| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= price_mapping.countries.pluck(:name).join(', ') %></td>
      <td><%= price_mapping.currency.code %></td>
      <td><%= price_mapping.program.name %></td>
      <td><%= price_mapping.active %></td>
      <td><%= price_mapping.default %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

with line

```
price_mapping.countries.pluck(:name).join(',')
```

I got countries' names like

```
Åland Islands, Algeria, Zimbabwe
```

now I want to sort all my @collections according to the first country name
for example, if a collection has countries [zimbabwe, Afghanistan, pakistan] it will be the last record and which have countries like [Afghanistan, zimbabwe, canada] it will be the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can get it simply by using Order with includes

```
@collection = @collection.includes(:countries).order('countries.name ASC').page(params[:page]).per(per_page)
```

I don't know when I tried to do this with join I got repeated records and I have to add distinct and after that order did not work.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe smth like this?

`@collection = @collection.joins(:countries).order('countries.name ASC').page(params[:page]).per(per_page)`

Comment: but now I'm getting one record multiple times